# data transfer to ip address using osi model

Tags: networking, routes, ip, packet, osi

consider the below case :

sender is sending a data to a particular Ip address. But when the packet is routing between the hops and moving meanwhile the device which has that ip address is out from the network and a new device come in to network.since the ip address are dynamic , considering a case  that previously used ip address is alloted to this new device because it is not in use. now the packets will deliver to new device that enter with that ip.

But that packet is not intended to send to that device.

how to solve this problem ?

if there are any misunderstanding you can help me

thank you in advance

i read articles but not able to figure it out